# Inline assembly code within my C ARDUINO program for a LED delay function

Tags: c, assembly, arduino, embedded, inline-assembly

I been set the task to replace the delay function in this simple blink arduino program

```
int ledPin = 13;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(ledPin,OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  delay(1000);
}
```

So far I've I have this for the assembly function :

```
asm volatile(
" lp1:   ldi r17,10         ;                \n"
" lp2:   ldi r16,100        ;                \n"
" lp3:   ldi r18,50         ;                \n"
" np:    nop                ;                \n"       
"        dec r18            ;                \n"
"        brne np            ;                \n"
"        dec r16            ;                \n"
"        brne lp3           ;                \n"
"        dec r17            ;                \n"
"        brne lp2           ;                \n"
"        sbiw r30,1         ;                \n"
"        brne lp1           ;                \n"
"        ret                ;                \n"
);
```

I'm not sure if I'm right so far, but what I'm mainly confused with is how I'm going to call the function later in the program, so I can call it as many times I want

Will be thankful for any help

Comment: Tasked by whom to replace it with what? Is this your homework?

Comment: It's not homework, just a summer uni project, I'm not asking for the answer, just a little guidance or a little help, its a small part of a bigger program I've already done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`asm volatile` is typically used for embedding assembly snippets inside C routines. So, in your example, you can write a simple C function which contains just the given assembly code (**nb:** you'll need to remove the `ret` instruction because the C function will handle function returning for you). Then, you can simply call the C function wherever/whenever you want.

An alternative would be to move the code to an actual assembly file, but then you'd have to worry about the actual C calling conventions for whatever compiler/platform you're using (this includes function arguments, if any).

As a rule of thumb, I'd recommend the former approach of embedding it in a C function, as the specifics of function calling is left to the compiler, and you still get the benefits of assembly code.